# Content negotiation in Spring MVC

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am writing a RESTful web application with Spring 3, and part of my application needs to process the data according to the requested media type.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String process() {
  if(requested_media_type_is_xml) {
     processXml();
  }
  else if(requested_media_type_is_json) {
     processJson();
  }
  return something;
}
```

Aka, my application logic is completely different if client requests different media type, so it seems Spring's ContentNegotiatingViewResolver or message converter are not very useful in this case because I want to route the request to different processing code rather than run the same code snippet and render them with different format according to the requested media type.

As far as I know, in JAX-RS, Jersey for example, you can use @Consume annotation for this. I wonder what is the Spring way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@RequestMapping` annotation has an optional `headers` attribute that allows you to narrow the mapping to requests with specific headers, e.g. to match XML:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", headers = "content-type=application/xml")
```

You can also specify multiple variants:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", headers = [{"content-type=application/xml","content-type=text/xml"}])
```

It's a little bit low level, but does the job.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. That is useful to me. Do you know if Spring will do the content negotiation job and request routing according to this?  And if client sends the "Accept" header like "text/html,application/xml;q=0.9", will this still work? Is it possible to use wildcard here, "\*/\*" and "text/*" for example?

Comment: @nybon: Good question - the `headers` attribute supports `*` wildcards, so it should work fine.

Comment: I did some tests, and here are my findings:

1) For multiple media types in "Accept" header, you can use:
    <pre>headers = "Accept=application/json,application/xml"



2) You can specify multiple @RequestMapping annotations with different "Accept" headers:
    @RequestMapping(..., headers = "Accept=application/xml")
 public Object getXml(...) {...}
    @RequestMapping(..., headers = "Accept=application/json")
 public Object getJson(...) {...}

Comment: In this case, Spring will decide for you which format is preferred by clients.
For example, if client sends a request with "Accept" header like "application/json;q=0.9,application/xml;q=0.95", Spring will route this request to the getXml method to handle this request, and this is exact what I want to achive. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10):

Although skaffman's answer is correct, I found in the latest Spring release (3.1 M2), there is an alternative and better way to do this, using `consumes` and `produces` values:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pets", consumes="application/json")
public void addPet(@RequestBody Pet pet, Model model) {
    // ...
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets/{petId}", produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Pet getPet(@PathVariable String petId, Model model) {
    // ...
}
```

Please check out more details here:
http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements-2/

Update:

Here are the official Spring documentation about this:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces

Comment: How can you attach the `@Controller` notation to a method?

Comment: Hmm, I simply copied this piece of code snippet from Spring's official blog entry as I listed above, http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements-2/. It seems there is some error in the code they posted.