# Spring MVC Controller with JSON and JSP

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

Can the same method in a controller be used for both JSP and other MIME types (like XML and JSON)?

I know of the following ways to resolve views in Spring MVC.

1. Return a `String` with the view name and add attributes to the `Model` or `ModelMap`
2. Return a `ModelAndView` with the view name and model
3. Return an `Object` with a `@ResponseBody` annotation

I use 1 or 2 when I am dealing with JSP and 3 when I want to return JSON or XML.

I know I can use two methods and with the `@RequestMapping(headers="accept=application/xml")` or `@produces` annotations to define which MIME types they handle, but is it possible to do this in just one method?

The controller logic is pretty simple and it seems like unnecessary duplication to have two different methods mapped which return the same exact model, or is this just simply the way it's done?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568414/content-negotiation-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @ebaxt I know you can use `RequestMapping` to allow one method to respond with JSON and the other with JSP. The question was asking how one would handle both JSON and JSP in the same method.

Comment: Ah - sorry, didn't catch that :)

Comment: @ebaxt based on your comment and the number of examples that use multiple methods it seems this is just not the way it's meant to be done. As is usually the case I think is an example of me fighting against the framework to do something that *seems* right (even though there is an obvious solution).

Comment: Just wondering if you've tried using `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` as per my answer below?

Comment: @nickdos Yes, but I failed to mention the fact that I was interested in weather or not it is possible to do this without having to explicitly define view resolvers in the spring XML. I used this approach because I ended up needing to set other properties which also require XML config and it works well.

Comment: I had a very similar question but using the Grails framework. The solution ended up being to use a grails filter to intercept the response and output the appropriate content type there. You **could** use the same technique in Spring with s servlet filter(?). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876570/grails-2-produce-json-output-automatically-like-spring-3-x-does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is straight forward in Spring MVC 3.x...

You basically write your controller methods for just normal JSP page views and then you configure a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` bean in your Dispatcher servlet config., which looks at the requested mime-type (or file extension) and returns the appropriate output type.

Follow the instructions here: [Spring 3 MVC ContentNegotiatingViewResolver Example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/)

Comment: Thanks! This works and it's what I ended up using. I also found it useful to set the `modelKeys` field of my `MappingJacksonJsonView` to keep it from rendering the whole model, this way only the key defined in `modelKeys` gets rendered in JSON while the rest of the model is available to the JSP view.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same requirement recently, and below is my code. validateTicket returns jsp name and sendForgotPassword mail returns json. My spring version is 4.0.0.RELEASE. Of course, if I need to return complex json then I'd definitely register Jackson converter - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/forgot-password")
public class ForgotPasswordController {

@RequestMapping(value="/reset-password", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String validateTicket(@RequestParam String ticket, @RequestParam String emailAddress) {
    return "resetPassword";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/send-mail", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody String sendForgotPasswordMail(@RequestParam String emailAddress) throws LoginException {
    return "{\"success\":\"true\"}";
}
}
```